# Calculate difference and mean over groups in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks as follows:

```
ID1    ID2     timestamp   x    y
0      0       43          1    40
0      0       53          20   41
0      0       63          21   41
0      1       73          5    100
0      1       75          6    99
0      1       83          7    87
1      0       100         34   23
1      0       200         0    0
1      0       210         0    22
1      0       222         22   15
2      0       300         22   15
2      1       450         22   15
2      1       451         22   15
```

Now, for each group of ID1 and ID2 I would like to calculate the time difference (max - min timestamp) and the mean of x and y. The resulting dataframe should look as follows:

```
ID1    ID2     timestamp   x    y
0      0       20          14   40.6
0      1       10          6    95.3
1      0       110         14   15
2      0       300         22   15
2      1       1           22   15
```

How can this be done? I could use `df.groupby(["ID1", "ID2"])` to group but I don't know how to calculate the difference and mean in situ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
df.groupby(["ID1", "ID2"]).agg({
   'timestamp': lambda x: x.max() - x.min(),
   'x': 'mean',
   'y': 'mean'
}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

I will using `np.ptp`

```
df.groupby(['ID1','ID2'],as_index=False).agg({'timestamp':np.ptp,'x':'mean','y':'mean'})
   ID1  ID2  timestamp   x          y
0    0    0         20  14  40.666667
1    0    1         10   6  95.333333
2    1    0        122  14  15.000000
3    2    0          0  22  15.000000
4    2    1          1  22  15.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't post what you tried, I guess a read at [this piece](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) of documentation may be of great help to your question.

[At the beginning of that page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine), the split-apply-combine method is explained.

Hope this helps.